# THREE.js custom Object class with imported mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm new to THREE.js.
I'm trying to create a custom class that extends THREE.Mesh to add to my scene. My idea is that the custom class must contains an imported mesh via json loader, but all my attempts to make it have failed.

Here is my code:

```
THREE.ImportedMesh = function(){
    this.type = 'ImportedMesh';

    this.load = function(url){
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load(url, function(geometry,materials){

            THREE.Mesh.call(self,geometry,new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
        });
    };
};
THREE.ImportedMesh.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Mesh.prototype );
THREE.ImportedMesh.prototype.constructor = THREE.ImportedMesh;
```

and here errors printed in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: this.updateMorphTargets is not a function

Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: Where did you define self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
THREE.ImportedMesh = function(){
  this.type = 'ImportedMesh';

  THREE.Mesh.call(this);
  var self = this
  this.load = function(url){
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(url, function(geometry,materials){
       self.material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
       self.geometry = geometry
    });
  };
};
THREE.ImportedMesh.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Mesh.prototype );
THREE.ImportedMesh.prototype.constructor = THREE.ImportedMesh;
```

Comment: it works! thank you so much Pailhead;I have another  question, how should I modify this code if I want to use a THREE.SkinnedMesh instead of a THREE.Mesh?